# ISA Server deployment asking for advice

Tags: isa-server

I am going to deploy ISA server 2006 on Windows Server 2008 x64 Enterprise. Some basic questions,

1. ISA Server 2006 is the most recent version?
2. I am going to deploy internal web site publish feature and firewall feature. What is the bottleneck and suggested H/W configuraiton? Is network always the bottleneck for ISA Server -- if so, I need to add more network adaptors to ISA Server;
3. I heard ISA Server has only 32-bit version, the Server 2008 is x64, is that ok to deploy 32-bit ISA server on x64, any bottleneck?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 2):

ISA 2006 is the current version of ISA.  [**Forefront Threat Management Gateway (TMG)**](http://www.microsoft.com/forefront/edgesecurity/isaserver/en/us/tmg-beta.aspx) is the successor to ISA 2006, but is currently in beta.  TMG is 64-bit only.  Based on this [**Technet blog post**](http://blogs.technet.com/isablog/) the RC is due out in the fall.  Not sure how quickly you're looking to deploy, but you might want to have a look.

Sorry, but my ISA experience goes back to ISA 2000 so my hardware info wouldn't really be relevant for you...

Comment: Thanks! 1. So, ISA Server 2006 has only 32-bit version? 2. Any H/W recommendation and bottleneck for ISA Server, e.g. whether dual network card will improve performance?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure ISA 2006 only runs on Win 2003 x32.

Comment: Correct. There is no edition of ISA that will install on Server 2008. I know this because I've tried. It all comes up with 'Not Available', except for the management console. You will have to deploy a 2k3 box, or wait for TMG.